# Call a VBA Macro in an exel Workbook from Visual Studio

Tags: excel, vba, vb.net, visual-studio, excel-addins

I have an excel workbook that runs some VBA code when a button is clicked. The function i want to call is shown below. I want to call the function from Visual Studio using VB. Is there any way of making an instance of the workbook and calling the function? (Excel Add-ins are needed for the function which is why I need the workbook.) Thanks in advance guys.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Offline_Click()
```

Comment: Can you alter the workbook code? Calling an private member is much, much more difficult than calling a public one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wanting to invoke a `Click` event handler means one thing: you're looking at a macro that's implemented in the event handler itself.

Move it out. Handlers are invoked by their event source; invoking them "manually" is terrible practice; you don't want to do that. Not to mention handlers can only exist in a class module, which means you need to get ahold of an *object instance* of that class in order to be able to locate its public members - its *private* members will be even more complicated to get to. If you're lucky the class is a worksheet module, so you get a workbook-scope instance of it for free.

In any case, the last thing you want to do is "just make the handler `Public`" and invoke it directly. *Refactor* instead:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Offline_Click()
    GoOffline
End Sub
```

Ideally you'd put the method in a standard module:

```
Public Sub GoOffline()
    '...
    ' all the code that's currently in CommandButton2_Offline_Click
    '...
End Sub
```

That way all you need to do is invoke `Application.Run` with `"ModuleName.GoOffline"` as an argument, from your .NET code.

As for *making an instance of the workbook*, there's a factory method for that: `Workbooks.Open` - your .NET code will need to have an `Excel.Application` instance to work with.

Comment: Perfect I'll give it a go, the CommandButton2_Offilne_Click() method might have thrown people off. It's acctually called from the event handler already so all I have to do is make that public.

Comment: I have been able to call the function from VB, I ran into an issue in regards to the add-in I'm using. The add in is ATPVBAEN.XLAM! (Analysis ToolPak). It tells me that the add-in isn't there even though it works when called using excel.